# Finish a Stripe subscription at year end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, subscription

I am having difficulties creating a custom subscription system using Stripe. My product has a **yearly** billed price.

The first time the user subscribes can be any date (let's say June 18th).

I want my subscriptions to end at 31 december of the current year, no matter the time the user subscribed.

After the sub ends, it renews automatically at 31 december for the new year (with the yearly billed price).

I tried using subscription schedules and it works fine **but the user cannot cancel his plan and gets automatically chargee for the new sub cycle**.

Has anyone faced a similar problem and if so, what was your solution?

Comment: Did you try setting [`end_behaviour: 'cancel'`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-cancel_at) parameter on the Subscription Schedule? This should ensure the Subscription is cancelled at the end of your configured phases.

Comment: But I want it to be renewed on the end of the phase. Problem is the user can't cancel the plan on the Stripe Customer Portal if it's on a schedule.

Comment: Got it - I misunderstood. In that case I don't think a Subscription Schedule is the path you need to take. Have you instead tried setting the [`billing_cycle_anchor`](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle) on creation?

Comment: I've thought about it. Let's say a subscription is created and I catch the relevant webhook. Then I instantly update the subscription and set its billing_cycle_anchor at december 31st? Will there be any side effects if the sub's price has a yearly billing and I set the anchor before that?

Comment: Yes, the initial invoice will be [prorated](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#new-subscriptions).

Comment: Ok, I will try to create a new subscription and follow this workflow. I hope it'll work :)

Comment: It doesn't work. You can't update billing_cycle_anchor to a timestamp on an existing subscription.

Comment: Yes, that's outlined on the doc I shared. Why can't you just set it on creation?

Comment: You mean, before I go to checkout session I create a new subscription, attach a predefined yearly-billing price to it, set its billing_cycle_anchor to year end and proceed with the checkout?

Comment: It's probably best you write in to Stripe's [support](https://support.stripe.com/contact) to get more help.

Comment: Will do. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help!